# How to execute sum if selection returns no element in R?

Tags: r, tibble

I have an `if` loop over multiple `data.frame`-s. I subset the data based on one of the variables and `sum` the entries based on another variable. My problem is that the selection sometimes returns a zero element `tibble` and so the `sum` function throws an error. Is there an elegant way to make the `sum` function execute these cases and consider the empty `tibble` as zero? It works nicely with a `data.frame` but does not with a `tibble`. I am sure there should be a solution with `tibble` as well.

```
#tibble
data<- tibble:: tibble("A" = c(1, 1, 2), "B"= c(2, 2, 1), "C"= c(10, 20, 30)) 
good<- data[data$A == 1,]
sum(good[good$B == "1",'C'])

#data.frame
data<- data.frame ("A" = c(1, 1, 2), "B"= c(2, 2, 1), "C"= c(10, 20, 30))
good<- data[data$A == 1,]
sum(good[good$B == "1",'C'])
```

Comment: `aggregate(C ~ A + B, data=data, FUN=sum)` or `tapply(data$C, list(data$A, data$B), FUN=sum)`; please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/grouping-functions-tapply-by-aggregate-and-the-apply-family

Comment: you can use chain operators `data %>%
  summarise(total = sum(C[A == 1 & B == 1])) %>%
  pull(total)`

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, .(C = sum(C)), .(A, B)]
```

if we need to have a comparison

```
setDT(data)[A== 1 & B == 1, .(total = sum(C))]
```